# Can't connect to IoT Central using X509 certificates

Tags: azure-iot-central

Using the sample code from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-connect-raspberry-pi-csharp), I've been able to connect to IoT Hub using DPS with a Group Enrollment based on X509 certs. However, using the same code and certs to connect to Central, the registration fails with:

ProvisioningClient RegisterAsync...Failed
Custom allocation failed with status code: 401
ProvisioningClient AssignedHub: ; DeviceID: 
Failed to register device

In both cases (DPS and Central) the Root certificate has been uploaded and verified successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, although the API returns 401 the device is created, but it's not associated to any device template. Once the association is made ("manually"),  the next calls work as expected.

This behavior is changing with the new Plug and Play features.